# Where does shared prefrences data are stored in Android device?

Tags: system

I want to know where Android stores the data of SharedPreferences in actual Android devices?

In PC I found this data under `/data/data/pkg_name/shared_prefs/pkg_name.xml`

Answer (score 4):

Well, the path is right. It's

```
/<datadir>/<pkg_name/shared_prefs/<pref_name>.xml
```

Where `<datadir>` is usually `/data/data`

Comment: okay but in device where do i find this .xml?

Comment: Have you looked at `/data/data/<pkg_name/shared_prefs/`?

Comment: i have samsung galaxy y in that where do i find this path?

Comment: Try `adb shell` to open a shell and `cd` into the path. You may need root to do so.

Comment: you are not getting me properly. in Actual phone where do i type adb command?

Comment: Oh sorry, since you mentioned in your profile that you had some Android Development experience I assumed that you are familiar with `adb`: Check out http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html

Comment: yeah i am android developer and i have found already this adb command and sharedprefrences.xml file on PC. but i want to verify that file on Real device.

Comment: If your device has root access, it  might be just easier to get RootExplorer and browse to the location on the device

Comment: how do i get the root access?